# Why do values ​disappear after scrolling in Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listadapter

[image]

***Data before scrolling***
[image]

***Data after scrolling***
[image]

---

The problem with my app is shown in the pictures above.

After entering the data, if i scroll after adding the item as scrollable, the data disappears.

As a further explanation, sometimes the entered data appears in other items that have been added.

To explain the app, it is an exercise recording app, and it uses a `multi-type recycler view`.

I used `ListAdapter` and also `DiffUtil`. And the picture is related to the `Detail item`.

`TextWatcher` was used to save the entered data.

I've been searching a lot to solve this.

The two most searched solutions are [here](https://www.solutionspirit.com/on-scrolling-recyclerview-change-values/)

1. using `getItemViewType()`, `getItemId()`
   ->I used this method as shown in this link, but it didn't solve the problem.
2. Using `setIsRecyclable(false)` inside the holder
   -> This method worked. But I heard that `setIsRecyclable(false)` is a function that does not `recycle`.
   If i use this, isn't it a good way to do it because there is no advantage to using `RecyclerView`?

***RoutineAdapter.java***

```
public class RoutineListAdapter extends ListAdapter<Object, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    RoutineListAdapter.OnRoutineItemClickListener routinelistener;
    RoutineListAdapter.OnRoutineAddClickListener routineAddListener;

    final static int TYPE_ROUTINE = 1;
    final static int TYPE_ROUTINE_DETAIL = 2;
    final static int TYPE_ROUTINE_FOOTER = 3;

    public RoutineListAdapter(@NonNull DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Object> diffCallback) {
        super(diffCallback);
    }

    // add routine interface
    public interface OnRoutineAddClickListener {
        public void onAddRoutineClick();
    }

    public void setOnAddRoutineClickListener(RoutineListAdapter.OnRoutineAddClickListener listener) {
        this.routineAddListener = listener;
    }

    // add/remove detail interface
    public interface OnRoutineItemClickListener {
        public void onAddBtnClicked(int curRoutinePos);
        public void onDeleteBtnClicked(int curRoutinePos);
        public void onWritingCommentBtnClicked(int curRoutinePos);
    }

    public void setOnRoutineClickListener(RoutineListAdapter.OnRoutineItemClickListener listener) {
        this.routinelistener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        View itemView;
        if(viewType == TYPE_ROUTINE){
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.routine_item, parent, false);
            return new RoutineListAdapter.RoutineViewHolder(itemView);
        }
        else if(viewType == TYPE_ROUTINE_DETAIL){
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.routine_detail_item, parent, false);
            return new RoutineListAdapter.RoutineDetailViewHolder(itemView);
        }
        else {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.add_routine_item, parent, false);
            return new RoutineListAdapter.RoutineAddFooterViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Object curItem;
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case TYPE_ROUTINE:
                curItem = getItem(position);
                setRoutineData((RoutineListAdapter.RoutineViewHolder) holder, (RoutineModel) curItem);
                break;
            case TYPE_ROUTINE_DETAIL:
                curItem = getItem(position);
                RoutineDetailModel item = (RoutineDetailModel) curItem;
                ((RoutineListAdapter.RoutineDetailViewHolder) holder).bind(item);
                ((RoutineDetailViewHolder) holder).weight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        item.setWeight(((RoutineDetailViewHolder) holder).weight.getText().toString());
                    }
                });
                break;
            case TYPE_ROUTINE_FOOTER:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void setRoutineData(RoutineListAdapter.RoutineViewHolder holder, RoutineModel routineItem){
        holder.routine.setText(routineItem.getRoutine());
    }

    public Object getRoutineItem(int position) {
        if(getCurrentList() == null || position < 0 || position >= getCurrentList().size())
            return null;
        return getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return getCurrentList().size() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position == getCurrentList().size()) {
            return TYPE_ROUTINE_FOOTER;
        }
        else {
            Object obj = getItem(position);
            if(obj instanceof RoutineModel) {
                return TYPE_ROUTINE;
            }
            else {
                // obj instanceof RoutineDetailModel
                return TYPE_ROUTINE_DETAIL;
            }
        }
    }

    private class RoutineViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView routine;
        public Button addSet;
        public Button deleteSet;
        public Button comment;

        public RoutineViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            routine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.routine);
            addSet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_set);
            deleteSet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_set);
            comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.write_comment);

            addSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(routinelistener != null && getAdapterPosition() != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                        routinelistener.onAddBtnClicked(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

            deleteSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(routinelistener != null && getAdapterPosition() != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                        routinelistener.onDeleteBtnClicked(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

            comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(routinelistener != null && getAdapterPosition() != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                        routinelistener.onWritingCommentBtnClicked(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class RoutineDetailViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView set;
        private EditText weight;

        public RoutineDetailViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            set = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set);
            weight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.weight);
        }

        private void bind(RoutineDetailModel item) {
            set.setText(item.getSet().toString() + "set");
            weight.setText(item.getWeight());
        }
    }

    private class RoutineAddFooterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        public RoutineAddFooterViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_text);
            ConstraintLayout regionForClick = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clickable_layout);
            regionForClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (routineAddListener != null) {
                        routineAddListener.onAddRoutineClick();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

***UPDATED***

***Adapter***

```
public class RoutineListAdapter extends ListAdapter<Object, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

//  detail add / remove iterface
    public interface OnRoutineItemClickListener {
        public void onAddBtnClicked(int curRoutinePos);
        public void onDeleteBtnClicked(int curRoutinePos);
        public void onWritingCommentBtnClicked(int curRoutinePos);
        public void onWritingWeight(int curRoutinePos, View view); // write weight
    }

    public void setOnRoutineClickListener(RoutineListAdapter.OnRoutineItemClickListener listener) {
        if(this.routinelistener != null)
            this.routinelistener = null;
        this.routinelistener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Object curItem;
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case TYPE_ROUTINE:
                curItem = getItem(position);
                setRoutineData((RoutineListAdapter.RoutineViewHolder) holder, (RoutineModel) curItem);
                break;
            case TYPE_ROUTINE_DETAIL:
                ((RoutineListAdapter.RoutineDetailViewHolder) holder).bind();
                break;
            case TYPE_ROUTINE_FOOTER:
                break;
        }
    }

 private class RoutineDetailViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView set;
        private EditText weight;

        public RoutineDetailViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            set = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set);
            weight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.weight);

            weight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                  routinelistener.onWritingWeight(getAdapterPosition(), itemView);
                }
            });
        }

        private void bind() {
            RoutineDetailModel item = (RoutineDetailModel) getItem(getAdapterPosition());
            set.setText(item.getSet().toString() + "set");
            weight.setText(item.getWeight()); // Setting the saved value
        }
    }
```

***Activity***

```
public class WriteRoutineActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WritingCommentDialogFragment.OnDialogClosedListener {
  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_write_routine);

        initViews();
        setPageTitle(getIntent());
        setRoutineRecyclerview();

        diffUtil2 = new RoutineDiffUtil2();
        listAdapter = new RoutineListAdapter(diffUtil2);
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        routine_rv.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        listAdapter.setOnRoutineClickListener(new RoutineListAdapter.OnRoutineItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onWritingWeight(int curRoutinePos, View v) {
                RoutineDetailModel item = (RoutineDetailModel) listAdapter.getRoutineItem(curRoutinePos);
                EditText weight = v.findViewById(R.id.weight);
                item.setWeight(weight.getText().toString()); // This is saved to set the value again when recycled.
        });
    }
}
```

*If you need any other extra code, please tell me*

Comment: Does removing the line involving the  `TextWatcher` solve your problem?

Comment: @Henry Twist I just cleared the TextWatcher related methods. But the result is the same. 
And in my opinion, `TextWatcher` is a necessary method to save the data entered in real time

Comment: The problem is that you're adding it multiple times to the same view when scrolling. I am surprised it's not the cause but still it might cause other issues.

Comment: @Henry Twist Sorry, but can you explain more easily about `adding it multiple times to the same view`? I don't understand well.

And why could `TextWatcher` be a problem in the future?

Comment: Because your views are being recycled, the same view is being reused when you scroll to represent a different item, so `onBindViewHolder` is called again, therefore adding another `TextWatcher`.

Comment: @Henry Twist You mean it's `recycled`, so the views you added initially and the data entered will be recycled for items added later?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230098/discussion-between-henry-twist-and-ybybyb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies with your `TextWatcher` that you're adding in `onBindViewHolder`.

At the moment you have it setup so that every time the `RecyclerView` binds a view (which can happen multiple times per actual view), you're adding a new `TextWatcher` and then also setting the text to the item's weight, which is then triggering the previous watchers you added, setting the item's weight to something else, in this case an empty string.

What you should be doing is either removing all listeners before you add another one, or add the listener in `onCreateViewHolder` and use the holder's adapter position to get your item.

---

Here is some pseudocode to clarify my suggestions:

**Adding the listener in `onCreateViewHolder`**

```
RoutineDetailViewHolder {
    private EditText weight;

    RoutineDetailViewHolder {

        weight.addTextChangedListener {
            
            items[adapterPosition].setWeight(...)
        }
    }
}
```

**Removing the listeners before binding again:**

```
RoutineDetailViewHolder {
    private EditText weight;
    private TextWatcher weightWatcher;

    void bind() {
    
        weight.removeTextChangedListener(weightWatcher);
        
        weightWatcher = new TextWatcher();
        weight.addOnTextChangedListener(weightWatcher);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.

You mean there are two solutions.

But you told me to handle the listener in `onCreateViewHolder`, which is the same as setting the listener inside the `ViewHolder`?

The reason I ask this is, when I processed the `TextWatcher listener` in the `RoutineDetailViewHolder`, it still got the same result.

Comment: Do you want to update the code in the question with what you've tried? Then I can take another look.

Comment: i edited the code, Moved `TextWatcher listener` inside `RoutineDetailViewHolder` rather than `onBindViewHolder()`.

Comment: Is `RoutineDetailViewHolder.bind(...)` still being called in `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: Um... yes. maybe it's like that..

The first way to remove the listener is to implement the listener in the activity?

Honestly, the second way is I'm not sure how to add a listener in `onCreateViewHolder`.

Comment: For example in the `RoutineViewHolder`, you're calling `addSet.setOnClickListener(...` when the view holder is initialised (which is `onCreateViewHolder`). So you just need to do exactly the same sort of thing for the text changed listener.

Comment: I've added some clarification in my answer

Comment: I did what you said, but when I do getItem(getAdapterPosition()) in the constructor, I get an Index error. i edited the code

Comment: OMG.. i solved it! Since we updated the code, would you please take a look?

Is this the code you intended or is there any more recommendable code?

But I don't know why my code works..

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, glad it's fixed!

Comment: thank you. I will ask you one last time. You gave me two solutions.

One is to remove all listeners before adding another listener, and the other is to add the listener to `onCreateViewHolder` and use the holder's adapter's location to fetch the item.

As you can see the code, I solved it in the second way.

But I am also curious about the first method.

If you look at my adapter code, there is a code that makes the listener `null`, but... is this?

Comment: I meant removing the `TextWatcher`s from the `EditText`. I'll give a quick example in my answer.

Comment: So, in this case, is it okay to implement `TextWatcher` in `onBindHolder`?

Comment: Yes, as long as you remove the old one before you add a new one. The issue was that you were adding multiple watchers to each view, so as long as you get around that, any solution is fine!

Comment: Thank you for your long time help. Sorry to bother you. Thank you so much.