# Edit text data missing when scrolling in a recycler view?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a recycler view of edit texts, however when scrolling my data of edit texts sometimes disappear and sometimes repeat itself in other edit texts.

I also use two functions in my adapter to get the values passed for edit texts in the main activity in my case (product & price) but as I said I don't get the right values so I'm looking for your help guys.

This is my recycler view adapter:

```
class MyAdapter(var myList: List<ProductModelClass>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemToAddBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {}


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = ItemToAddBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(v)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {


        holder.binding.etProductName.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                val text: String = s.toString()
                myList[position].product = text
            }

        })





        holder.binding.etPrice.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                val text: String = s.toString()
                myList[position].price = text
            }

        })
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }


    fun getProduct(): ArrayList<String>{
        val productList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        for(element in myList) {
            productList.add(element.product)
        }
        return productList
    }


    fun getPrice(): ArrayList<String>{
        val priceList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        for(element in myList) {
            priceList.add(element.price)
        }
        return priceList
    }


}
```

Comment: btw i see that most people recommend to use a ViewModel that saves all these text data but i don't know how to implement that

Comment: To answer the question, i think the problem is that the TextChangedListeners are never removed from the view, so after the ViewHolders are recycled and re-binded, multiple listeners are added to the same EditTextView. To fix that, you need to remove the existing listener before adding new listener in onBindViewHolder(), or only create one listener in onCreateViewHolder and reuse it. Also, i think you may be missing the part that setting the EditTextView's text in on onBindViewHolder()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do values ​disappear after scrolling in Recycler View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66697774/why-do-values-disappear-after-scrolling-in-recycler-view)

Comment: i do what u guys told me and I replaced my  textChangeListener to my onCreateViewHolder but I face a problem that my getAdapterPosition() is always equal to -1